# Download Bloomberg Terminal's information using R

Tags: r, automation, finance, bloomberg, rblpapi

I've been looking for some clear examples for this approach. I know it requires an API in some cases. I've found the libraries `Rblpapi` and `RblDataLicense`, but I haven't been able to find a clear example to base on.

I need to download data from the DDIS function in the bloomberg terminal for a credit risk modeling I'm currently developing.

I'll appreciate a lot if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the vignette and manual, which you can find at https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rblpapi .

I have never tried to do this, but I don't think you can just download the DDIS data as is. I suspect you'd have to recreate it by finding all the bonds for the company(ies) you're interested in and then downloading the info you want for each one. Looks as though you'd need to explore the bsrch() function.